# '/' is added to my redirect URL when I try to pass query params

Tags: spring, url

I have a spring app that has a controller to redirect the user to a specific URL based on data they send me.  If the data is wrong, I direct them to a url with an error code and description.  However, when I do this redirect, it is adding a `/` before the query parameters, making the redirection wrong.  So the code would look like:

Controller.class

```
String Failure_URL="https://www.google.com";

if(response.getStatus()!=200) {
   //there was an error, so redirect to error URL

   //map response to my object class
   MyObject obj = new MyObject(response);
   String redirectURL = Failure_URL + "?error_code=" + obj.getError_Code()
        + "&description=" + obj.getDescription();

  }
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + redirectURL);
```

When I look at my network trace during testing, I can see the Location header is being set correctly. `https://www.google.com?error_code=001&description=System+Error`, however when it makes the redirect the URL turns into `https://www.google.com/?error_code=SECB001&description=System+Error`, making those queryparams a path URI.  Is there any way to stop it from doing this, it means these values aren't being set as params correctly.  Is this due to the `+` in the description, and should I encode it?

Answer (score 2):

You should use Spring's `UriComponentsBuilder` to build URL programmatically and avoid such weird behaviours.

You can build URL like below:

```
String Failure_URL = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
            .scheme("https")
            .host("www.google.com")
            .queryParam("error_code", "error_code_value")
            .queryParam("description", "description_value")
            .build().toUriString();
```

In case you need to add `/` in URL, you can add `.path("/")` wherever it is required.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I tried using the URL builder, and in my controller everything looks good.  It isn't until I send my response as a redirect it adds a "/", but I tried it a different way than your answer, so let me try this as well